# add delay to ng-keyup in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS application, I have a binding to the input field on **ng-keyup** to call a function every time value of the input field is changed.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="logoText.text" ng-keyup="updateTextLogo();">
```

This function updates text on a canvas and performs few more actions which take 2-3 seconds.

While type each letter with little delay (slow) is working fine by fast typing results in overlaying of canvas data.

**Is it possible to add delay to execute the function on keyup?**

Ex., Current scenario is that if a user has to type **Hello** the function is called on each letter.

I want to add a delay so that if the user has entered **Hell** within the dealy, the **Hell** word will be processed together instead of each letter.

Comment: $scope.updateTextLogo= function() {
        if ($scope.logoText.text >= 4) executeSomething()
 };

Comment: Hey, I have just given above test as an example. The user is not restricted to the number of letters. I just want to call the function after a few delays. Like if a user only enters **H** and then wait for 2 seconds, the function will be called.

Comment: Hey, I found this plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/HfPDC4veoW9KlVrC7Tly?p=preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the $timeout service:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="logoText.text" ng-keyup="triggerTimer();">

var timerStarted = false;
$scope.triggerTimer = function() {
  if(!timerStarted) {
    $timeout(updateTextLogo, 2000);
    timerStarted = true;
  }
}
```

The function updateTextLogo should reset the timerStarted flag, so that the timer can be started again, when there come further characters.

```
var updateTextLogo = function() {
  timerStarted = false;
  // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using angular 1.3 or above, you have debounce in ng-model-options.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="logoText.text" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" ng-keyup="triggerTimer();">
```

Debounce affects the assigning of value to the scope variable.

Comment: Hey, mine is **1.2.7**. How to do in version less than 1.3?